# algorithm to sample function so that integral is unaffected

Tags: algorithms, sampling

I have an array with a hundred thousand entries representing the x and y values of a function. Since I frequently need to integrate this function (in a product with other functions) I am looking for an algorithm that allows me to reduce the number of function points without changing the value of the integral. I am looking for a way to reduce the number from hundred thousand down to one thousand so that

$\int_{\text{ thousand}} f = \int_{\text{ hundred thousand}} f$

Right now I am taking every 100th point, but in the end I end up with an error of 10^-7 which is rather large for my application.

Is there a smart way to choose these points so that the integral remains the same?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: Since I need the actual integration to be very fast I am sort of restricted to simple algorithms like simpson or trapezoidal. So I am looking for a method to choose the integration points so that the value of the integral doesn't change for one of these two integration routines.

Comment: @moderator: if there is a better se site to ask this question please feel free to move, I honestly didn't quite know where to ask this

Comment: Is that function less smooth near the array's boundaries? $\;$

Comment: It's reasonably well behaved everywhere. It's overall pretty similar to a cosine or sine.

Comment: I would look for a higher-dimensional analogue of [Gaussian quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature). $\;$

Comment: that would make the integral more accurate but usually involves finding the roots of some polynomials first, however I need the actual integration to be very fast, which is why am sort of restricted to simple integration algorithms like trapezoidal or simpson. I edited my question for clarification in that regard. But thanks for your comments, I really do appreciate them.

Comment: It's possible that this question would do better on [scicomp.se] SE. If it doesn't get answered here, consider flagging it for migration.

Comment: @ftiaronsem : $\:$ According to your question, you only need _one_ number of points, so your use of it would usually _not_ involve "finding the roots of some polynomials first", since you would only need to do that once. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: What are you doing with the functions?  If all you do is integrate it, then you can just store the integral (1 point).  So what other operations do we need to support on these functions?

Comment: @D.W. $\:$ He will be integrating products of his function "with other functions". $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: You are actually right about that. I would only have to do it once. Thanks for pointing that out. However I have no estimate on how the weights and points would change when I am integrating the product of functions. For all I know they could change drastically and severely upset the value of the integral if I used the old ones. By taking every 100th point I sort of know the error introduced by looking at the smoothness of the function. I am lacking a corresponding feeling for the more involved integration schemes. But I might just give it a try and see, thanks a lot for the idea.

Comment: Ideally I was hoping that there would be some theory of "data reduction" that preserves integrals. Much like simplectic integration schemes preserve the "energy" (speaking as a physicist) of the system.

Comment: How often would one of the terms in the product be the same function? $\;$

Comment: The product looks like f*g*h where g and h are different functions every time. f remains the same (which is why I want to optimize it).

Comment: Is f [even or odd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) with respect to x or y? $\;$

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it is even. why?

Comment: In that case, if the domain(s)'(s) of the variable(s) f is even with respect to are/is symmetric symmetric about zero, then the sample points and their weights can also be preserved by reflection over the other axes/axis, which would make finding a good weighted list of sample points easier. $\:$ I don't know how difficult it would be to solve for optimal weights given the set of points, so the two possibilities I can think of are doing that for each for each list of points you try in an optimization procedure, or directly optimizing the list of points and weights simultaneously. $\;\;\;\;$